# How to determine the application within a certain set of url schemes in iOS?

Tags: ios

(iOS App)When using ShareSDK(a sdk used to share) in the application need to set some url schemes, when I removed a url schemes, ShareSDK will remind me do not set the appropriate url schemes.

This means, ShareSDK can identify whether our application has set the corresponding url schemes. I'm doing the application also requires the use of a similar function, looking for a long time to find out how to solve.

My question is: How to determine the application within a certain set of url schemes in iOS?

Comment: Suddenly I thought I could to get to the current version number through code. like this  NSDictionary* infoDict =[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* versionNum =[infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSString*appName =[infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
NSString*text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",appName,versionNum];  The infoDic I log it ,whitch I found that it has log contain like this <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>aaa123</string>
   </array>

Comment: Then the problem has been solved.